# Java Graphics.drawString doesn't always work

Tags: java, graphics, drawstring

Has anyone ever run into this issue before? Sometimes the string displays, sometimes half of it, sometimes none of it. The issue is worsened when using VolatileImage instead of BufferedImage as a backbuffer.

```
public class Game3D {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game3D game = new Game3D();
    game.start();
}

public Game3D() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    canv = new GameCanvas();
    canv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.add(canv);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
private JFrame frame;
private GameCanvas canv;

public void start() {
    canv.createBuffer(canv.getPreferredSize());
    loadingScreen("Loading", 10);
}

public void loadingScreen(String msg, int done) {
    Graphics2D g = canv.img.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, canv.getWidth(), canv.getHeight());

        int sizeX = 400, sizeY = 50;
        int loadX = canv.getWidth() / 2 - sizeX / 2;
        int loadY = canv.getHeight() / 2 - sizeY / 2;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(loadX, loadY, sizeX, sizeY);
        g.fillRect(loadX + 2, loadY + 2, (int) (sizeX / 100F * done), sizeY - 3);

        int textX = canv.getWidth() / 2 - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(msg) / 2;
        int textY = canv.getHeight() / 2 - g.getFontMetrics().getHeight() / 2;

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(canv.font);
        g.drawString(msg, textX, textY);

    } finally {
        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

}

class GameCanvas extends Canvas {

```
GameCanvas() {
}
BufferedImage img;
Font font;

void createBuffer(Dimension dim) {
    img = new BufferedImage(dim.width, dim.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 16);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

Comment: For one thing, your code in the main isn't running in the swing thread. Try using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Comment: I ran the frame initialization code inside the swing thread, and it seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks man.

Comment: Don't mix Swing with AWT components!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needed to be ran in the SWING thread!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to call `frame.repaint();` in order to have what you draw show up properly though I'm not entirely certain. I just remember this being the cause of a few of my own problems when using Java GUIs.

Comment: Well, it's drawing more GUI components besides the string, and they are displaying. At this point, I only render the frame once to a BufferedImage, then store that later for repainting. The drawString call is never actually painting to the BufferedImage. Also, the issue seems to worsen when using a VolatileImage.